# how to configure Sweave it's work and recognize for Rpy2?

Tags: python, r, sweave, rpy2

how to configure Sweave it's work and recognize for  Rpy2?

I use this

```
 import rpy2.robjects as robjects

  R["library"]("utils")
  R["library"]("tools")
  R['sweave("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")']
  R['texi2dvi("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.tex", pdf=TRUE)']
```

but I get these errors

```
[File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 241, in   __getitem__
    res = rinterface.globalenv.get(item)
    LookupError: 'Sweave("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")' not found
     Traceback (most recent call last):]
```

thanks for your answers and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets to get an R object, then call it from Python. Or use () brackets to pass a line to R:

```
R["Sweave"]("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")
R('Sweave("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")')
```

Sweave needs a capital S (in my tests).

Answer (score 1):

Uh, does this work?  You're not doing all the R[] invocations the same way.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

R["library"]("utils")
R["library"]("tools")
R["sweave"]("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")
R["texi2dvi"]("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.tex", "pdf=TRUE")
```

(I've never used Rpy2 so this is totally guessing.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the R package importer would let you use autocompletion in your IDE or interactive shell and make the code more Python-like.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
utils.Sweave("/var/www/tmp/pywps/central.Rnw")
```